# Send a lot of variables during POST without limit

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where I can select multiple customers from a select, to send a communication via email.
Customers can be a lot... maybe > 3000.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
Message
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
Customers
<select name="customers[]" multiple>
  <option value="email@email.com">Customer 1</option>
  <option value="emailxxx@email.com">Customer 2</option>
  ...
   <option value="emailccc@email.com">Customer 3000</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

I have no access and can't modify limit of variables in `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` (actual limit = 1000)

So if I select all customers, not all variables are sent.

Is there a method to manipulate the form during send processing to workaround on this?

Maybe create a unique variable to send named `array_email_customers` and insert all emails, comma divided? Is this a good solution or there is a better way?

UPDATE: MORE INFO: The post not send immediatly the emails... it save all emails in a table (queue table) and a cron execute every 5 minutes, sending 100 records at a time

Comment: Assuming you are sending all 3000 customer's email in request, how would request look like in the end? Is there one variable for each email?

Comment: If you're sending a plain `form` submission, then no, there's nothing you can do. If you're using AJAX then you can break the request in to batches. However I'd argue that sending that many customer changes in one go is a really bad idea. What happens if the user's PC crashes as they're editing the 2999th user? Do they lose *everything*? Depending on your use case I would suggest you look in to sending every change individually, or only sending amended customer records, or changing the UI to make weight of data much less of a problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in that case somebody is going to find a broken window and PC.

Comment: that's where you'd see the user leap from the window @Rory in despair!

Comment: The post not send immediatly the email... it save all emails in a table (queue table) and a cron execute every 5 minutes, sending 100 records at a time

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan update request. See: The post not send immediatly the email... it save all emails in a table (queue table) and a cron execute every 5 minutes, sending 100 records at a time. BTW i've no problem to use ajax if needed. But how to pass all my variables without pain?

Comment: @Saharsh updated post. I'm not sure: customers (the mutiple select) is evaluated as ONE variable or N variables ?